# Using dictionary keys as references in JSON .NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to parse some JSON in this format:

```
{
    "Sources": {
        "Videos1": {
            "Order": "Default",
            "PathPattern": "Videos/**/*"
        },
        "Images": {
            "Order": "Default",
            "PathPattern": "Images/*.jpg"
        }
    },
    "MasterSource": "Videos1"
}
```

This should be able to represent a class like:

```
public class Playlist
{
    public Dictionary<string, Source> Sources { get; set; }

    public Source MasterSource { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Obviously, JSON.NET doesn't know how to convert a string to a `Source` or find it in a dictionary it needs to parse first. Aside from using `string` fields, then looking them up when a `Source` is gotten, is there a way I can do this using a JSON converter, or something else?

(NB: The `Sources` dictionary in the JSON will always come first)

Answer (score 1):

A simplified converter can look like this

```
public class PlayListConverter : JsonConverter<Playlist> {
    public override Playlist ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Playlist existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var json = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);
        var sources = json["Sources"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, Source>>();
        var master = json["MasterSource"].Value<string>();

        var result = new Playlist() {
            Sources = sources,
            MasterSource = sources[master]
        };

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Playlist value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And applied

```
public class Source {
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string PathPattern { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(PlayListConverter))]
public class Playlist {
    public Dictionary<string, Source> Sources { get; set; }

    public Source MasterSource { get; set; }

    // etc
}
```